# Pandas: split column into multiple columns with unique values

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
   A
0  Me
1  Myself
2  and
3  Irene
4  Me, Myself, and Irene
```

which needs to be turned into:

```
   Me  Myself  and  Irene
0  1   0       0    0
1  0   1       0    0
2  0   0       1    0
3  0   0       0    1
4  1   1       1    1
```

Looking for any suggestion.

Comment: just get dummy ?

Comment: `df = pd.get_dummies(df['A'])` should working perfectly.

Comment: No it does not. Example: if you have multiple files to work with, the dummy only gets the instances that are in one file. Example: if I don't have Irene, then Irene does not appear in dummy. But I need Irene in other files! See what I mean?

Comment: You example, is unclear , Please consider modify  it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by all possible categories:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Me', 'Myself', 'and', 'Irene']})
df2= pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Me', 'Myself', 'and']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Me', 'Myself', 'or', 'Irene']})

all_categories = pd.concat([df1.A, df2.A, df3.A]).unique()
print (all_categories)
['Me' 'Myself' 'and' 'Irene' 'or']

df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1.A).reindex(columns=all_categories, fill_value=0)
print(df1)
   Me  Myself  and  Irene  or
0   1       0    0      0   0
1   0       1    0      0   0
2   0       0    1      0   0
3   0       0    0      1   0

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df2.A).reindex(columns=all_categories, fill_value=0)
print(df2)
   Me  Myself  and  Irene  or
0   1       0    0      0   0
1   0       1    0      0   0
2   0       0    1      0   0

df3 = pd.get_dummies(df3.A).reindex(columns=all_categories, fill_value=0)
print(df3)
   Me  Myself  and  Irene  or
0   1       0    0      0   0
1   0       1    0      0   0
2   0       0    0      0   1
3   0       0    0      1   0
```

Comment: What does happen if you have one row with "Me, Myself, and Irene", where the comma is the separator?

Comment: @FaCoffee - Then is better `str.get_dummies` - `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Me, Myself, and Irene']})
print (df.A.str.get_dummies(', '))`