# How to make new columns from unique values of rows in a dataset

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, rows

I'm working with the Stackoverflow survey dataset. I need to extract the values from the `LanguageWorkedWith` column and create dummy columns based on unique values on the rows.

[image]
[image]

I need a column for each programming language and a value of 1 or 0 for each row.

Thank u!

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860987/pandas-split-column-into-multiple-columns-with-unique-values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: split column into multiple columns with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860987/pandas-split-column-into-multiple-columns-with-unique-values)